# Посоветуйте бесплатный API погоды

Tags: php, openweathermap

Вообщем ситуация следующая, компания занимается сдачей в аренду домиков, типа в аренду для отдыха. На главной странице сайта должна отображаться погода, температура, осадки ветер и т.д в данный момент.

Я не так давно в разработке, в условиях API пишут что использовать **не в коммерческих целях**, это означает что нельзя создавать виджет погоды на главной странице для сайта с арендой трех домиков?

По сути API используется в таком случае в коммерческих целях, или я не прав?
Заранее спасибо за ответ)

Comment: вроде как бесплатный - https://www.gismeteo.ru/api/

Comment: "*это означает что нельзя создавать виджет погоды на главной странице для сайта с арендой трех домиков*" и если один домик, тоже нельзя